# Ensure only dependencies are in node modules and not dev dependencies

Tags: npm

I have a script in my `package.json` like so:

`"build": "npm install && npm prune --production"`

This command will install all dependencies and then remove the devDependencies.

Is there a command to do this in one hit? For example, a command that ensures that production-level dependencies are the only ones existing in node_modules?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is `npm install --only=prod`.